# How do I change foreach to for in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I want to print the word exist in a text file and  print "match" and "not match". My 1st text file is: `xxaavv6J`, my 2nd file is `6J6SCa.yB`.

If it is match, it return like this:

```
Match found: 
Match found: 
Match found: 
Match found: 
Match found: 
Match found: 6J
Match found: 
Match found: 
Match found:
```

My expectation is just print `match` and `not match`.

```
$X = Get-Content "C:\Users\2.txt"
$Data = Get-Content "C:\Users\d.txt"
$Split = $Data -split '(..)'

$Y = $X.Substring(0, 6)

$Z = $Y -split '(..)'

foreach ($i in $Z) {
    foreach ($j in $Split) {
        if ($i -like $j) { 
            Write-Host ("Match found: {0}" -f $i, $j)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The operation `-split '(..)'` does not produce the result you think it does. If you take a look at the output of the following command you'll see that you're getting a lot of empty results:

```
PS C:\> 'xxaavv6J' -split '(..)' | % { "-$_-" }
--
-xx-
--
-aa-
--
-vv-
--
-6J-
--
```

Those empty values are the additional matches you're getting from `$i -like $j`.

I'm not quite sure why `-split '(..)'` gives you any non-empty values in the first place, because I would have expected it to produce 5 empty strings for an input string "xxaavv6J". Apparently it has to do with the grouping parentheses, since `-split '..'` (without the grouping parentheses) actually does behave as expected. Looks like with the capturing group the captured matches are returned on top of the results of the split operation.

Anyway, to get the behavior you want replace

```
... -split '(..)'
```

with

```
... |
    Select-String '..' -AllMatches |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    Select-Object -Expand Value
```

You can also replace the nested loop with something like this:

```
foreach ($i in $Z) {
    if (if $Split -contains $i) {
        Write-Host "Match found: ${i}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach using regex '.Match()' should also do it.
I have added a lot of explaining comments for you:

```
$Test = Get-Content "C:\Users\2.txt" -Raw         # Read as single string. Contains "xxaavv6J"
$Data = (Get-Content "C:\Users\d.txt") -join ''   # Read as array and join the lines with an empty string. 
                                                  # This will remove Newlines. Contains "6J6SCa.yB"

# Split the data and make sure every substring has two characters
# In each substring, the regex special characters need to be Escaped.
# When this is done, we join the substrings together using the pipe symbol.
$Data = ($Data -split '(.{2})' |                                   # split on every two characters
        Where-Object { $_.Length -eq 2 } |                         # don't care about any left over character
        ForEach-Object { [Regex]::Escape($_) } ) -join '|'         # join with the '|' which is an OR in regular expression

# $Data is now a string to use with regular expression: "6J|6S|Ca|\.y"

# Using '.Match()' works Case-Sensitive. To have it compare Case-Insensitive, we do this:
$Data = '(?i)' + $Data

# See if we can find one or more matches
$regex = [regex]$Data
$match = $regex.Match($Test)
# If we have found at least one match:
if ($match.Groups.Count) {
    while ($match.Success) {
        # matched text: $match.Value
        # match start:  $match.Index
        # match length: $match.Length
        Write-Host ("Match found: {0}" -f $match.Value)
        $match = $match.NextMatch()
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "Not Found"
}
```

Result:

> `Match found: 6J`

Comment: Thanks for the great solution. But still have 1 problem, when It's not match, It doesn print "Not Found" . It looks like the else statement not work.

Comment: I also need to always cut the last 3 character in the $Test data, before check the match

Answer (score 0):

Further to the [excellent Ansgar Wiechers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55062761/3439404): if you are running (above) *Windows PowerShell 4.0* then you could apply the `.Where()` method described in  *Kirk Munro*'s exhaustive article [ForEach and Where magic methods](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/):

> With the release of Windows PowerShell 4.0, two new “magic” methods
>   were introduced for collection types that provide a new syntax for
>   accessing `ForEach` and `Where` capabilities in Windows PowerShell. 
>   These methods are aptly named **`ForEach`** and **`Where`**. I call
>   these methods “magic” because they are quite magical in how they work
>   in PowerShell.  They don’t show up in `Get-Member` output, even if you
>   apply `-Force` and request `-MemberType All`.  *If you roll up your
>   sleeves and dig in with reflection, you can find them; however, it
>   requires a broad search because they are private extension methods
>   implemented on a private class*.  Yet even though they are not
>   discoverable without peeking under the covers, they are there when you
>   need them, they are faster than their older counterparts, and they
>   include functionality that was not available in their older
>   counterparts, hence the “magic” feeling they leave you with when you
>   use them in PowerShell.  Unfortunately, these methods remain
>   undocumented even today, almost a year since they were publicly
>   released, so many people don’t realize the power that is available in
>   these methods.
>   …
>
> **The Where method**
>
> `Where` is a method that allows you to filter a collection of objects.
>   This is very much like the `Where-Object` cmdlet, but the `Where`
>   method is also like `Select-Object` and `Group-Object` as well,
>   includes several additional features that the `Where-Object` cmdlet
>   does not natively support by itself. This method provides faster
>   performance than `Where-Object` in a simple, elegant command.  Like
>   the `ForEach` method, any objects that are output by this method are
>   returned in a generic collection of type
>   `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection1[psobject]`.
>
> There is only one version of this method, which can be described as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> Where(scriptblock expression[, WhereOperatorSelectionMode mode[, int numberToReturn]])
> ```
>
> As indicated by the square brackets, the `expression` script block is
>   required and the `mode` enumeration and the `numberToReturn` integer
>   argument are optional, so you can invoke this method using 1, 2, or 3
>   arguments.  If you want to use a particular argument, you must provide
>   all arguments to the left of that argument (i.e. if you want to
>   provide a value for `numberToReturn`, you must provide values for
>   `mode` and `expression` as well).

Applied to your case (using the simplest variant `Where(scriptblock expression)` of the `.Where()` method):

```
$X    = '6J6SCa.yB'  # Get-Content "C:\Users\2.txt"
$Data = 'xxaavv6J'   # Get-Content "C:\Users\d.txt"

$Split = ($Data -split '(..)').Where({$_ -ne ''})

$Y = $X.Substring(0, 6)
$Z = ($Y -split '(..)').Where{$_ -ne ''}    # without parentheses
```

For instance, Ansgar's example changes as follows:

```
PS > ('xxaavv6J' -split '(..)').Where{$_ -ne ''} | % { "-$_-" }
-xx-
-aa-
-vv-
-6J-
```